# How to bind selected row-values of a kendo grid with textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to bind values of a selected row with text boxes

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {

var selectedRow = null;
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    Items: [],
    onUpdateItems: function (data) {
        alert('updating items');

        document.getElementById("id").value = data.models[0].Id,
             document.getElementById("ic").value = data.models[0].CurrentCurrencyCode,
               document.getElementById("isn").value = data.models[0].ShortName,
               document.getElementById("ifn").value = data.models[0].FullName,
                document.getElementById("icp").value = data.models[0].ContactPerson,
              document.getElementById("iadd").value = data.models[0].Address1,
              document.getElementById("icc").value = data.models[0].CompanyCity,
              document.getElementById("ics").value = data.models[0].CompanyState,
              document.getElementById("icco").value = data.models[0].CompanyCountry,
              document.getElementById("izpc").value = data.models[0].ZipPostCode,
              document.getElementById("ita").value = data.models[0].TelArea
    },
    products: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/Companies/GetAllCompanies2",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false

            },
            create: {
                type: "PUT",
                url: "/api/Companies/UpdateDefCompny",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false

            },
            update: {
                url: "/api/Companies/SaveDefCompny",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },

            destroy: {
                url: "/api/Companies/Delete", // here you need correct api url
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && data) {
                    if (operation == "update") {
              // here i call the function change

         viewModel.Items.trigger("change",data);


                    }
                    else {
                    return JSON.stringify(data.models[0]);
                    }
                }

            }
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            //data:"Data",
            total: "Count",

            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "int" },
                    CurrentCurrencyCode: { editable: true, type: "int" },
                    ShortName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    FullName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    ContactPerson: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    Address1: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    CompanyCity: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    CompanyState: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    CompanyCountry: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    ZipPostCode: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    TelArea: { editable: true, type: "string" }

                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
    })
});

viewModel.Items.bind('change', function (e) {
   //function called
    viewModel.onUpdateItems(e);
});

kendo.bind(document.getElementById("example"), viewModel);

 }
```

I use command edit instead of update in HTML code command row then it works.  Here is my HTML-code:

```
<!--data-editable="inline"-->

<div id="example">
    <div id="kendoGrid"
         data-role="grid"
         data-pageable=" true"
         data-sortable=" true"

         data-filterable="true"
         data-toolbar="['create','save', 'cancel']"
         data-columns="[

        { 'field': 'Id', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'CurrentCurrencyCode', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'ShortName', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'FullName', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'ContactPerson', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'Address1', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'CompanyCity', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'CompanyState', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'CompanyCountry', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'ZipPostCode', 'width': 100 },
        { 'field': 'TelArea', 'width': 100 },
        { command: ['update'],  title: 'Actions', width: '250px' },

        ]"
         data-bind="source: products"
         style=" height :500px">
    </div>
</div>
<div>

    <input id="id" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: Id " />
    <input id="ic" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  CurrentCurrencyCode " type="text" />
    <input id="isn" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: ShortName " type="text" />
    <input id="ifn" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  FullName " type="text" />
    <input id="icp" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  ContactPerson " type="text" />
    <input id="iadd" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  Address1 " type="text" />
    <input id="icc" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  CompanyCity " type="text" />
    <input id="ics" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  CompanyState " type="text" />
    <input id="icco" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  CompanyCountry " type="text" />
    <input id="izpc" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: ZipPostCode " type="text" />
    <input id="ita" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:  TelArea " type="text" />

    <input id="Update" type="submit" value="Update" />
</div>
```

the function change() that is triggered when i use update operation it goes to onUpdateItems()
there are 2 problems:

1-i have to use binding method instead of document.getelementbyId

2-call a function without using edit in command only use update in html code
when i use update it doesnot work but if i use

```
data-editable="inline"
```

along with edit it works

Comment: Your code is very hard to debug - can you try removing the parts that are  not relevant for this question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h0ha4jyv/ js fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you add `data-bind="change: onChange" and data-selectable="true"`

Then on onChange function you can do

```
function (e) {
            selectedRow = this.select();
            var item = this.dataItem(selectedRow);
            kendo.bind($("#textbox-wrapper"), item);
        }
```

Dont forget to add id to the div that wrap your textbox and replace the binding on this code  `kendo.bind($("#textbox-wrapper"), item);`

From your question where you wanted to  bind values of a selected row with text boxes, I think your question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480814/bind-a-row-data-of-kendo-grid-with-text-boxes-onclick/30485867#30485867) where he wanted to bind the selected row to textbox, datepicker, or checkbox. Except for this question its not using mvvm. I also already provided a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/wqayq8py/1/) but it's not mvvm

Edit i have created the mvvm one here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/4puezjLb/2/)

Comment: i performed crud using sql database and  mvvm thanks